# Finding a 1-parameter family of solutions for $(x + 2y - 4)\ dx - (2x -4y)\ dy = 0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was trying to find a 1-parameter family of solutions for

$$(x + 2y - 4)\ dx - (2x -4y)\ dy = 0 \quad (Q) $$.

This is what I have done so far. 
$$ u = x +  2y -4 \implies du = dx + 2dy \quad (1) $$
$$ v = 2x -  4y \implies dv = 2dx - 4dy \quad (2) $$

solving for $dx$ and $dy$ from $(1)$ and  $(2)$

$$ dx = \frac{2\ du + dv}{4} $$
$$ dy = \frac{2\ du - dv}{8} $$

substituting $u,v,dx,dy$ into $(Q)$

$$ u\bigg(\frac{2\ du + \ dv}{4}\bigg) - v\bigg(\frac{2\ du - dv}{8}\bigg) = 0$$

$$ 4u\ du + 2u\ dv - 2v\ du + v\ dv = 0 $$

$$ (4u - 2v)\ du + (2u + v)\ dv = 0 $$

Let $ u =tv \implies du=t\ du + v\ dt$

$$  (4tv -2v)(t\ dv + v\ dt) + (2tv + v)\ dv = 0 $$
$$ 4vt^2\ dv + 4tv^2\ dt - 2tv\ dv - 2v^2\ dt + 2tv\ dv + v\ dv = 0 $$
$$ 4t^2\ dv + 4tv\ dt - 2t\ dv - 2v\ dt + 2t\ dv + dv = 0$$
$$ (4t^2 -2t + 2t +1)dv + (4tv -2v)dt = 0 $$
$$ (4t^2 +1)dv + v(4t -2)dt = 0 $$
$$ \frac{dv}{v} + \frac{4t - 2}{4t^2 + 1}\ dt = 0 $$

After Integrating

$$ \ln\ |v| + \frac{1}{2}\ln(4t^2 + 1) - \arctan(2t) = c$$

Also substituting values for $v$ and $t$
$$ \ln(|2x-4y| )  + \frac{1}{2}\ln\Biggr(4\bigg(\frac{x+2y}{2x -4y}\bigg)^2 + 1\Biggr) - \arctan\Biggr(2\bigg(\frac{x+2y}{2x - 4y}\bigg)\Biggr) =  c $$

$$ \ln[4(x -2y)^2 + 2(x-2y)^2]  - 2\arctan\bigg(\frac{x+2y}{x-2y}\bigg) = 0 $$

**Please how do I arrive at this answer (the right answer to the question $ (Q) ) $** 
$$ log[4 (y -1)^2 + (x -2)^2 ] - 2\arctan\frac{2y -2}{x -2} = c $$

Comment: @LutzLehmann that is true. Please I have updated. I want to know if the steps I took is right.

Comment: This now looks more plausible. However, the logarithmic terms both are not right, the first lacks the absolute value, the second a factor $\frac12$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Please I have added it and also updated. But why is it absolute value ?

Comment: You get the reference solution by first determining the equilibrium position and thus reducing to a purely linear problem. You did not use the correct expression for $t$. // $v$ can have legitimately negative values, thus $\ln|v|$. // Apply logarithm laws to combine both logarithms to a simpler term. You still get a different formula, it is not easy to see that the difference amounts to a constant. Compare with complex logarithm, the difference is a complex factor with non-zero phase.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Please what correct expression should I use for $t$

Comment: You should use $u$ and $v$ as defined, you somehow forgot the constant term.

Answer (score 2):

The solution curves of this equation can also be parametrized so that they are solutions of the linear system
$$
\pmatrix{\dot x\\ \dot y}=\pmatrix{2&-4\\ 1&2}\pmatrix{x\\ y}+\pmatrix{0\\ -4}
$$
Setting $z=x+2iy$ this results in the complex-valued scalar DE
$$
\dot z = (2x-4y)+i(2x+4y-8)=2(1+i)z-8i
$$
with solution $z(s)=Ce^{2(1+i)s}+2(1+i)$ so that taking the logarithm of $(x+2iy)-2(1+i)=Ce^{2(1+i)s}$ gives
$$
{\rm Ln}(x+2iy)-2(1+i))=\ln|(x-2)+2i(y-1)|+i\arg((x-2)+2i(y-1))\\=(a+2s)+i(b+2s)+2ik\pi
$$
Now eliminate $s$.

---

Of course one also can, before taking the logarithm, multiply the whole identity by a factor. With the factor being $(1+i)$ to replicate the right structure of the original DE gives
\begin{align}
{\rm Ln}&((x-2y)+i(x+2y)-4i)\\&=\ln|(x-2y)+i(x+2y-4)|+i\arg((x-2y)+i(x+2y-4))\\&=(a'+2s)+i(b'+2s)
\end{align}
which translates into what your solution should look like
$$
\ln\left((x-2y)^2+(x+2y-4)^2\right)-2\arctan\left(\frac{x+2y-4}{x-2y}\right)=c
$$

Comment: Please where did I go wrong in my steps ? Mine looks similar to the final answer but not the same

Comment: @EALehn : Look back on how you defined $u$. Then how you used it when replacing back $t$ with $\frac uv$. If you correct that, your solution should be equivalent to the reference solution, up to the discontinuity location of the arcus tangent which gives different lines in both solutions..